# How to apply CLEAN() formula to entire Excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file with almost 50 columns and 10,000 rows. These contain non-printable characters in some cells; I want to remove these characters from all cells in the sheet.

It would be difficult to apply the `CLEAN()` function to each and every column. Is there an alternative?

Comment: DO you know what those `non-printable characters` are?

Comment: I mean do you know the ASC code of those characters?

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I am not sure about the characters t.they are not ASCII characters.Even i am unable to visible them ,they visibile like square boxes and question marks some thing like that

Comment: Sorry ,No Idea about ASC code of those.Actually i am unable to see them .they are coming like new line character.but it's not new line character

Comment: <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4joyoYeTfSndXNqTDktaE56Mnc/edit?usp=sharing">Excel file</a>
you can downlaod the file from this link and you can obsevre the cells D1 and E1

Comment: Checking the file out

Comment: FYI From `CLEAN` documentation: *In the Unicode character set (Unicode: A character encoding standard developed by the Unicode Consortium. By using more than one byte to represent each character, Unicode enables almost all of the written languages in the world to be represented by using a single character set.), there are additional nonprinting characters (values 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, and 157). **By itself, the CLEAN function does not remove these additional nonprinting characters**.*

Answer (score 4):

I can't see it visually.. If you see that character at the end of the cell text, then you can find that value using the below code

```
debug.Print asc(right(range("D1").Value,1))
```

Simply replace 110 with that value in the code below.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Cells.Replace What:=Chr(110), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

[HERE](http://www.asciitable.com/) is the ASCII table for your reference.

Answer (score 2):

To apply the excel `CLEAN` function on each cell of the first 50 columns and 10000 rows:

```
Sub cleanSheet()
    Dim r As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each r In Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10000, 50))
        r = WorksheetFunction.Clean(r)
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI Just for fun I ran this on my machine to see how long it would take; it took about 1 hour. Looping through cells can be excruciatingly slow.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett it takes less than a minute on my machine

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett If you know a way to restrict the loop to non-empty cells I'm more than interrested

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create another sheet then, in the first cell, write the clean formula `=Clean('sheet1'!A1)` and enter.

Now drag the columns and rows. You will get your cleaned up data in this sheet.
You can also use the trim function in the same way.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Thank you z̫͋! This was just what I was looking for!

I noticed in the comments there was some call to reference only non-empty cells. I used this instead of the cell references and it vastly improved the processing time.

```
For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

Hopefully this helps a little. (Though I'm pretty late to the party.)